# Applying RANSAC to vector<Point2f> for similarity transform

Tags: c++, opencv, sift, ransac

I used CV_RANSAC option at findHomography function but now I want to use estimateRigidTransform. Thus I can no more use CV_RANSAC.

I want to eliminate outliers of my SIFT featured matched data and apply estimateRigidTransform. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have a 2D or a 3D transform? The estimateRigidTransform-function assumes that your transformation is 2D. I have done a project where I used both findHomography and estimateRigidTransform with SURF, but this was by a fixed distance and in one plane. 

Can you explain what you want to compare?

Comment: I am working on panorama, thus 2D transform to stitch image to reference image. I used findHomography to stitch it projectively but it becomes spread out at the end. Thus I want to use similarity transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that worked for me:

- Use SURF descriptor and extractor for getting feature points
- Use FLANN-matcher to get good matches
- Crosscheck all the matches. Here is how I did that:

  ```
  std::vector<Point2f> valid_coords_1, valid_coords_2;
  std::vector< DMatch > valid_matches;
  //-- Show detected matches


  int counter;
  float res;
  for( int i = 0; i < (int)good_matches.size(); i++ ){
    counter = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < (int)good_matches.size(); j++){
      if(i!=j){
        res = cv::norm(keypoints_1[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt - keypoints_1[good_matches[j].queryIdx].pt) - cv::norm(keypoints_2[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt-keypoints_2[good_matches[j].trainIdx].pt);
        if(abs(res) < (img_1.rows * 0.004 + 3)){ //this value has to be adjusted
          counter++;
        }
        //printf("Match good point %d with %d: %f \n", i, j, res);
      }
    }
   /* printf( "-- Good Match [%d] Keypoint 1: %d (%f,%f)  -- Keypoint 2: %d (%f,%f) Distance: %f  \n", i, good_matches[i].queryIdx, 
      keypoints_1[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt.x, keypoints_1[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt.y, 
      good_matches[i].trainIdx, 
      keypoints_2[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt.x, keypoints_2[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt.y, 
      good_matches[i].distance); */
    //printf("Point nr %d: has %d valid matches \n", i, counter);
    if(counter > (good_matches.size() / 10)){
      valid_matches.push_back(good_matches[i]);
      valid_coords_1.push_back(keypoints_1[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
      valid_coords_2.push_back(keypoints_2[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
    }
  }
  ```

  - Used the estimateRigidTransform-function.

I hope this helped in some way. Please let me know if you need further information :)

Comment: THX! I will check this out! I was going to implement ransac by myself but this will help alot!